# How to access Cloud Storage for Firebase if I already have access token?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In my desktop app (UWP), I am trying to create `StorageClient` for accessing Cloud Storage for Firebase using the following code:

```cs
public StorageClient CreateStorageClient(string accessToken)
{
    var service = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = new HttpClientInitializer(() => accessToken),
        ApplicationName = StorageClientImpl.ApplicationName,
    });

    StorageClient client = new StorageClientImpl(service);
    return client;
}

public class HttpClientInitializer : IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer
{

    public HttpClientInitializer(Func<string> getFreshTokenMethod)
    {
        _getFreshTokenMethod = getFreshTokenMethod;
    }

    private readonly Func<string> _getFreshTokenMethod;

    public void Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _getFreshTokenMethod());
    }
}
```

For authentication I use [FirebaseAuthentication.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet) so I have Firebase auth token available (in addition to Google access_token).

If I create `StorageClient` with above code using Firebase auth token, any upload operation fails to error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

For a comparison I am successfully using the same Firebase auth token (in the same app) with the [Firestore library](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/).

I tried also using Google access_token, but it fails to error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "my.email@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to my-app.appspot.com/users/[uid]/image.jpg."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "my.email@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to my-app.appspot.com/users/[uid]/image.jpg."
 }
}
```

I know there is other [Firebase storage](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet) library available, but I would prefer using Google library if possible because I am already using their Firestore library (even though they do not support UWP officially).

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have is because you need to add a role to the member you want to use (email that you are using in your UWP app).

The role you need to assign to the member is storage.objectCreator and you can follow this link to do it [Grant roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart#grant_other_roles_to_the_same_member)

If you want to read more about roles in Cloud Storage you can read the info of this link [Roles in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

Comment: I can access the same file, with the same login email using the other library (Firebasestorage.net) and also using my Android application, so I don't think the issue is related to roles. Thanks for the idea anyway.